Can clang-format arrange each function entirely on one line?
I'd like to format a set of C++ files so that each function or function template is defined entirely on one line. With input such as:
template <typename T>
void foo(int i)
{
  return;
}

template <int I, typename T>
struct Bar {
  Bar()
  {
  }

  static int testsmf(double d)
  {
    return 42;
  }

  template  <typename U>
  inline void testmft() const {
    int i;
    double longname1;
    double longname2;
    double longname3;
    double longname4;
    double longname5;
  }
};

int main()
{
  return 0;
}

I might look for output approximately so:
template <typename T>void foo(int i){  return;}
    
template <int I, typename T>
struct Bar {
    Bar()  {  }
    
    static int testsmf(double d)  {    return 42;  }
    
    template  <typename U>  inline void testmft() const {    int i;    double longname1;    double longname2;    double longname3;    double longname4;    double longname5;  }
};

int main(){  return 0;}

Currently my clang-format style file (named cf) is minimal:
ColumnLimit: 0
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All

I test via clang-format -style=file:./cf test.cpp, but alas the only noticeable change in the output is that each function's opening brace is placed on the same line as its name. I earlier tried starting with the output of clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config, and changing the two style options as above, but this also didn't work. Setting ColumnLimit to a large value such as 1000 makes no difference either. I am using ClangFormat version 18.1.3.

I would be very sad if my code was reformatted to look that way

Clang-format can format most code in a sensible way. It cannot format all code according to any crazy formatting standard.

Why on earth would you want that?

Multiple declarations / statements on a single line doesn't seem to be possible according to the LLVM guys but the rest seems possible.

BLUF: No, it won't do what you want.
You shouldn't use your desired format for all sorts of reasons, and plenty of comments will list them.
But you didn't ask if it was a good idea. clang-format can be configured to get you part of the way there. Until there is a parameter for what 'short' means, the options aren't there.
I am not sure if you can get it to completely ignore semicolons, but here is how you would start
First you want to get a .clang-format file: clang-format -dump-config > .clang-format
Then you need to disable your column limit in the file
ColumnLimit: 0
CompactNamespaces: true

The following options are around 'short' block not sure what the definition of short is. Not entirely against these on an individual bases.
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortCaseExpressionOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: AllIfsAndElse 
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All

you want to disable various 'break' options
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
BreakAfterReturnType: None //Note: i believe this translates to automatic
                           //Which means it is dependent on penalties
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
Break****
PackConstructorInitializers: CurrentLine

of note is
BreakTemplateDeclarations: No

If you are onelineing things, you might want to remove character wherever possible
RemoveBracesLLVM: true
RemoveParentheses: ReturnStatement 
SpaceBefore****

*Note RemoveParentheses: ReturnStatment Might be dangerous(change code)
use https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html to get more info on options.

RemoveParentheses: ReturnStatement is absolutely terrible since it can change what's returned. This option should be removed from clang-format - or be made to not remove parentheses if it changes the type of what's returned. Anyway, I didn't see your suggestions doing all that much difference.  foo is on 4 lines instead of 1 etc. Please include the result you get when running with this config.

@TedLyngmo I agree that this is a bad idea. And to truly get where OP wants to be, they need to add a parameter defining what is short 'short'.

So, what result did you get when using this config?

I added an edit with one of the Break*** that is particularly relevant to example code. Most Every parameter that starts with 'Break' needs to be set to no/false/leave, but some items don't allow disabling, like 'BreakInheritanceList' doesn't have a 'none' option.

Alas, no: the output was much the same as my two line effort. Here are a few comments:
No such key:
AllowShortCaseExpressionOnASingleLine
No such key:
BreakAfterReturnType (? I also tried AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType)
Break**** (Every option starting with Break? What values should they be set to?)
No such key:
BreakTemplateDeclarations (? I also tried AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations)
No such key:
RemoveParentheses
SpaceBefore*** (Every option starting with SpaceBefore? What values should they be set to?)

@user2023370 AllowShortCaseExpressionOnASingleLine is available from clang-format 19. Anyway. The advice in this answer won't get OP far. I have something that makes everything except multiple declarations / statements on a single line as a I mentioned in a comment - but even the LLVM guys says that's not even possible or within their scope. One would have to show a really big use-case for it for them to even contemplate implementing support for it

@TedLyngmo Fair enough, time to move on I guess. As a point of learning, where is it my idea of using a minimal 2-line style file is going wrong? Are there implicit options which are always applied?

@user2023370 "where is it my idea of using a minimal 2-line style file is going wrong?" - Did you think I meant your comment when I wrote "The advice in this answer won't get OP far"? I meant Macoft's answer.

@TedLyngmo No, I knew exactly what you meant. It was your sensible advice that made me think you might also have some intuition on why the 2-line style file I mention in my original post fails so utterly - is it not simply requesting for the line/column limit to be removed; and for "short" functions (presumably those that fit on one line) to be placed on one line.

Oh, as I mentioned in a comment under the question, multiple declarations on a single line isn't possible but the rest of your wanted result is feasible.
